# Fork MTB clearance problem

Tags: tire, fork

I have a felt Nine comp. It is a 29er with rockshox  forks. The clearance is poor with a continental rubber queen tyre. Is there anything I can do to increase the clearance? (we're talking 1cm, which results in quick mud jams.)

Comment: Really need more information - what year and model of shock, what size tire.

Comment: 2011/2012 I think. Recon I believe.

Answer (score 3):

I had a look at pics of the bike, and see the clearance is small on a 2.1 tire  - Rockshox Recon and the standard 29 x 2.1 are pretty standard across many bikes (mine included) and I have not heard of  a problem.  The Rubber Queen is a 2.4, so I would suggest going back to a 2.1 and see if you still have a problem (maybe the bike maker does know what they are doing when they choose tire sizes).  If you really want to stick to a 2.4 size, look around for a low profile tire.  However, the Recon is not an AM shock - it's designed for XC, where 2.1 is the more common size used and 2.4 has little advantage.

Generally the only thing you can do it go to smaller tire or replace the shock. Smaller tire is a cheaper option.

Another option would be to stick to drier tracks. If you are getting that much mud buildup despite having a lot of fun you are likely destroying the tracks you are riding. One of the key mountain biking rules is "Tread lightly".....

Comment: This said it all. If Mark W is needing wide tire and mud clearance, it is a clear indication for the need of another suspension, which would probably bring along other benefits such as longer travel and stiffer handling.

Comment: Good answer @mattnz. I would like to add that I am not destroying trails, these routes are bridleways too, so the horses have churned it all up. Drier tracks - ha. I wish, I live in Wales.

Comment: I guess thats true @heltonbiker though not an expense I really want.

Comment: Well, it's surprising how much fun one can get in mountainbike when one accepts the challenge to ride "underdimensioned" material on demanding trails. Let's not forget that, about just ten years ago, 2.1 were "fat tires" and 100mm was "long travel". And there were guys with such equipment who kicked ass even by today's standards. That's a way to look at it :o)

Comment: @MarkW - The only way I know to ride a horse trail is get a horse. I am lucky - where I ride the horse and bikes have separate trails. At least you have no worries about destroying the tracks - nothing worse than horses for that....